# Launch Condition for checking Visio 2010 installation does not work on Win 7 64 bit with Visio 2010 64 bit version

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in, visio, office-addins

We have a visio 2010 add in deployed using msi created with setup and deployment project in visual studio.
The setup project is having a launch condition to check the registry and prompt user if Visio 2010 is not installed.
RegKey - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Visio,
Root - vsdrrHKLM,
Value - CurrentlyRegisteredVersion

This works fine to prompt user when visio 2010 version is not detected on win XP, Win 7 (both 32 and 64 bit OS) with Visio 2010 32 bit. When it is run on win 7 64 bit with visio 2010 64 bit version  setup prompts user even if visio is installed.

Appreciate any pointers to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Visio` in the registry on my machine under HKLM or HKCU.

Instead check `HKCR\Visio.Application\CurVer`.  That value appears to be in the registry regardless of bitness of Visio and OS.